# Use sed with hdfs ls to make more optimize

Tags: shell, hdfs

I am trying to more optimize my code by using sed in same line with hdfs ls but error is coming.

> hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_RAW_DIR/MIC>>$PATH/note.txt | sed -i '1d'
>   PATH/note.txt

This my above code  showing error can there is way to use in same line

Comment: You should post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Your line does not really make sense

```
hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_RAW_DIR/MIC >> $PATH/note.txt
```

will append the output of `hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_RAW_DIR/MIC` to the end of the file `$PATH/note.txt`. The standard output passed to the pipe will be empty.

```
sed -i '1d' PATH/note.txt
```

will process the file but you forgot the `$`

Anther problem is that `$PATH` is a reserved variable the contains the list of directories where the shell looks for binaries.

So summarising:

```
hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_RAW_DIR/MIC >> $MY_PATH/note.txt ;  sed -i '1d' $MY_PATH/note.txt
```

Comment: Can't we use pipe operator (|) instead of semicolon

Comment: The pipe operator sends the output of the first command to the second. In your case you are using a file to store the result. You should maybe explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ShivamSharma
See if this is what you are trying to achieve.
hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_RAW_DIR/MIC | sed '1d' >> $MY_PATH/note.txt